# Is there a way to list files inside a docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Simple question: Is there a docker command to view the files inside a volume?

I run docker for windows which creates a MobyLinuxVM on my machine to run Docker. I can't get a remote desktop connection onto this machine like I can with an Ubuntu VM (which I also have running on my machine).

Therefore, I can't see a way to see what is inside my host volumes (as they are actually inside the MobyLinuxVM), where as if I ran docker on my Ubuntu VM I could remote onto the machine and take a look.

Therefore, is there a way I can run some sort of `docker volume` command to list what's inside each volume?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use a temporary container for this. I tend to use busybox for these temporary containers:

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               jenkins-home
local               jenkins-home2
local               jenkinsblueocean_jenkins-data
...

$ docker run -it --rm -v jenkins-home:/vol busybox ls -l /vol
total 428
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           327 Jul 14  2016 com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.GitLabPushTrigger.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           276 Aug 17  2016 com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.connection.GitLabConnectionConfig.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           256 Aug 17  2016 com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerPluginConfiguration.xml
drwxr-xr-x   28 1000     1000          4096 Aug 17  2016 config-history
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          6460 Aug 17  2016 config.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000        174316 Jun  2 18:50 copy_reference_file.log
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          2875 Aug  9  2016 credentials.xml
...
```

For a host volume, you can just replace the volume mount with the host directory name (fully qualified) in the `docker run` cli.

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v /path/on/host:/vol busybox ls -l /vol
```

Comment: tip: replace `ls -l /vol` with `sh` if you want some sort of shell access to dig deeper.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to the question (because it was asking about a docker command) but in case anyone arrives here like I did:

If you have Docker Desktop (on Windows at least) you can explore into a volume using the Docker Desktop GUI.  Just click on the volume, then switch to the "Data" tab at the top.

Quick and easy if you are just wanting to take a look around or copy out a file.

Comment: So helpful! Thanks for adding your answer. Works similarly on Docker Desktop for Mac. You can also choose to save the data from the docker volume as a `.zip` file and access it on your local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how widely applicable this is, but if you have root access I've just discovered that you can browse the contents of a volume at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<VOLUME_NAME>/_data`. `VOLUME_NAME` is as shown by `docker volume ls`.

I'm looking at an Ubuntu 18.04 VM running Docker 19.03.5 - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `docker volume inspect my-vol` if you want to inspect the volume however if you may want to list all file within the volume; You can use shell cli by executing the following commands:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> sh
ls
```

Comment: I don't think that will actually list files.

Comment: @DavidMaze, you can check, I have modified my answer