# Restoring mysql data from a Docker Volume

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-volume

It's the second time that when my local system (Mac OS) crashes and restarts, I lose the running Docker container of MySQL.  By "lose" I mean even `docker ps -a` doesn't show it.  It's vanished.

I am using the official mysql-server docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server) so luckily the data of `/var/lib/mysql` is in a volume.  And I am lucky that after the loss of the container, the volume is there.

The question is, how can I restore the data (e.g. a `mysqldump`) out of a Docker volume of `/var/lib/mysql`?

Answer (score 3):

### Step 1: Find and verify the volume

Via `docker volume ls` you can find the name of the volume.  Let's say it's `<abcdef>`.

Then, via `docker run -it --rm -v <abcdef>:/var/lib/mysql busybox ls -l /var/lib/mysql` make sure you see the files and the dates of the files matches your recent changes to the lost DB. (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46875500))

Optionally,  you can create a backup out of this volume via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62695427).

### Step 2: Create a new container, and mount this volume on

Whatever `docker run` command you are already using to start a MySQL container, add `-v <abcdef>:/var/lib/mysql_old` to it.  It should give you a fresh MySQL container up and running, without any issue.  **Your data is not loaded there yet**, just the files are accessible.

### Step 3: Copy and overwrite the MySQL data

Now, go into the shell of that container (e.g. `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash`) and do `ls /var/lib/mysql_old` to make sure the files from your volume are there.

Then, do `cp -R /var/lib/mysql_old/. /var/lib/mysql` (or `sudo cp ...` depending on the user you got in with) and then `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`. (Credits to [this tutorial](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-create-a-physical-mysql-backup))

### Step 4: Restart the container

Exit the container and do `docker stop <CONTAINER_NAME>` to stop the container.  Then start it again via `docker start <CONTAINER_NAME>`.  Voila! It should now be a DB with all your data.

Optionally, if you want to start off with a non-hacked container, you can do `docker exec <CONTAINER_NAME> sh -c 'exec mysqldump -uroot -p --databases <DATABASE_NAME>' > dump.sql` to get a mysqldump out of it, and import that `dump.sql` into a fresh new container via `docker exec -i <CONTAINER_NAME> sh -c 'exec mysql ' < dump.sql`.